# Why there is imageCreateFrom* if there is imageCreateFromString?

Tags: php, image, gd

I really can't understand why GD has different function for loading images such like:

```
imagecreatefromjpeg() 
imagecreatefrompng() 
imagecreatefromgif()
```

While there is a single function if the image is string?

```
imagecreatefromstring()
```

Indeed it's much better to read the image into the string and pass it to the function, something like:

```
$imgBlob = file_get_contents($imagePath);
imagecreatefromstring($imageBlob);
unset($imgBlob);  //> Free memory, but I am not interested in memory consumpation
```

? Or I am missing something ? This could led to potential confusion for new users

Maybe they just forgot to create a function `imageCreateFromFile()`?

**Ps.** Of course I am not interested about memory consumation using the `file_get_contents` method

Comment: Hmmm. Fair question. That's the PHP core library for ya....

Comment: Because PHP's aim in life is to be bloated full of useless stuff you could do easily with an extra line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`imagecreatefromstring()` runs a switch against the passed image type, checks if your system has support for that image type, and then actually runs the correct `imagecreatefrom*` function.

You can check out the source code to see this: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/gd/gd.c?source=cc (line 2280 for the function, line 2301 where it switches on the image type and calls the correct function).

So, the `imagecreatefromstring()` function is really just a helper wrapper. You'll get a very slight benefit from not running `_php_image_type` (line 2217) if you call the actual image type function.

Answer (score 2):

```
imagecreatefromjpeg() 
imagecreatefrompng() 
imagecreatefromgif()
```

create image resource from a file - you pass file path as parameter and that's the only acceptable input.

```
imagecreatefromstring()
```

creates image resource from string, not file - it could be virtually anything, you can even type in a content. For example you can use

`imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode('R0lGODlhAQABAJAAAP8AAAAAACH5BAUQAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICBAEAOw=='));`

to get 1x1 pixel transparent gif (useful for tracking gifs)

Granted, you could pass everything through `imagecreatefromstring`, but it would not be memory efficient - handling large images takes a lot of memory and with low memory limit that makes a huge difference.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, though - why was this architectural decision made? Why is there no `imagecreatefromfile()` that is format agnostic?

Comment: It might be the order they added things to PHP: `imagecreatefrom*` functions have been there since PHP 4 was released, `imagecreatefromstring` wasn't at first - it's a 4.0.4 addition. My guess is they have added file-format-specific functions, later made a format agnostic function, but it was too late to change what has already been released.
And since GD works and there isn't any real work done around this haven't changed for years.

Comment: @c2h5oh: i believe there is no difference even for memory consumation, because GD after imagecreatefromjpeg etc convert the image into raw format and the memory consumation is the same, with both function you will still have your image full loaded in memory

Comment: @yes123 that's true for the resulting image object, but doesn't account for the variable holding file contents. Of course you can unset it right after you are done with it, but it doesn't change the fact that peak memory usage will be higher - it might be the difference between success and out of memory error.

Comment: @c2h5oh: as i stated in my question, memory consumation isn't the point of the question

Comment: Well, it all boils down to: `imagecreatefrom*` and `imagecreatefromstring` serve a slightly different purpose and having two separate functions to create image object from different sources does make sense, but at the same time there is no real reason for `imagecreatefrom*` to be split into format specific functions - PHP could have had format agnostic function there, but it doesn't, most likely for historical reasons and backwards compatibility.

Comment: I found this post helpful. But c2h5oh, could you please elaborate on how imagecreatefromstring is not memory efficient? I am workinging amazon micro environment and the limit for usage is 615MB. An image would be around 1.5MB. Would base64 and image createfromstring be too big for my limited memory environment to handle? I got my code to work in a different environment. This amazon has very strict limit; and this may be why my code isn't working at amazon.

Comment: @coolcool1994 imagecreatefromstring creates an image from a string you already have in the memory, so in worst case scenario it doubles the memory requirement untill you get rid of the string. imagecreatefrom* functions on the other hand will accept a file resource and should gradually load the image while processing it - at no point you should have the whole image string in memory.

Comment: Okay thanks. So your answer seems to indicate having a micro amazon environment instead of a bigger one is not the source of the problem.

Comment: All image processing is VERY memory intensive. 800 x 600 px at 24 bits per pixel is around 1.4MB (close to 2 MB with transparency) and while any function modifies it the actual memory usage is double that.